# SwiftUi possible to make widget background clear or blurry?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, widget

I am trying to make widget background Blurry or totally transparent if possible!
and since I've already spent days searching for solution I started to believe apple has removed this feature!

here is my widget code :

```
struct widgetsEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
         
            VStack {
                
                Text("Time: testing")
                Text(entry.date, style: .time)
            }
            
        }.containerBackground(for: .widget) {
            Color.clear
        }
    }
}


struct widget_Medium: Widget {
    
    let kind: String = "widgets"
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        
        AppIntentConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) 
        { entry in
            
            widgetsEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
         .containerBackgroundRemovable(true)
         .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium])
         .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
         .description("This is an example widget.")
        
    }
}
```

as you can see in attached image its showing black background In Dark mode when I've used Clear color!

[image]

**is it possible make the widget transparent or blurry ?**

Answer (score 0):

its seems apple does not allow 3rd party apps to use blurry or transparent background widget .